# Sitecore WFFM : Creates a duplicate field section upon submission

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, web-forms-for-marketers

I tried almost every search combination I know for this issue over the internet; been reading articles that might help resolve the issue, but I wasn't able to find any help.

Debugging (no exception during debug process), and reading logs doesn't give much information (no exceptions in the log file).

If you know a post that is related to this, please comment below. Otherwise, let me give it a try here.

> **Edited:** Tried also in Sitecore Instance v.8.1 Update-2, same problem was encountered.

**Let me describe the issue:**

- Using SC Instance v.8.0 Update-3 (freshly installed with no customizations)
- Using WFFM v.8.0 Update-2 (compatible with SC instance 8.0-U3)

I have 11 field sections in a CONTACT US form page, here are:

The **Section A** is the 1st field section and the **Section K** is the 11th field section of my Contact Us page.

**Section A**

- A1 Single-line text field | NOT required
- A2 Single-line text field | NOT required
- A3 Single-line text field | NOT required
- A4 Single-line text field | NOT required
- A5 Single-line text field | NOT required
- A6 Single-line text field | NOT required
- A7 Single-line text field | NOT required
- A8 Single-line text field | NOT required
- A9 Single-line text field | NOT required
- A10 Single-line text field | NOT required

**Section B**

- B1 Single-line text field | NOT required
- B2 Single-line text field | **required WITH NUMBERS ONLY VALIDATION**
- B3 Single-line text field | **required WITH NUMBERS ONLY VALIDATION**
- B4 Single-line text field | NOT required
- B5 Single-line text field | NOT required
- B6 Single-line text field | NOT required
- B7 Single-line text field | NOT required
- B8 Single-line text field | NOT required
- B9 Single-line text field | NOT required
- B10 Single-line text field | NOT required

**Section C**

- C1 Single-line text field | NOT required
- C2 Single-line text field | NOT required
- C3 Single-line text field | NOT required
- C4 Single-line text field | NOT required
- C5 Single-line text field | NOT required
- C6 Single-line text field | NOT required
- C7 Single-line text field | NOT required
- C8 Single-line text field | NOT required
- C9 Single-line text field | NOT required
- C10 Single-line text field | NOT required

**Section D**

- D1 Single-line text field | NOT required

**Section E**

- E1 Single-line text field | NOT required
- E2 Single-line text field | NOT required

**Section F**

- F1 Single-line text field | NOT required
- F2 Single-line text field | NOT required

**Section G**

- G1 Single-line text field | NOT required
- G2 Single-line text field | NOT required
- G3 Single-line text field | NOT required

**Section H**

- H1 Single-line text field | NOT required
- H2 Single-line text field | NOT required
- H3 Single-line text field | NOT required
- H4 Single-line text field | NOT required

**Section I**

- I1 Single-line text field | NOT required
- I2 Single-line text field | NOT required
- I3 Single-line text field | NOT required
- I4 Single-line text field | NOT required

**Section J**

- J1 Single-line text field | NOT required
- J2 Single-line text field | NOT required
- J3 Single-line text field | NOT required
- J4 Single-line text field | NOT required

**Section K**

- K1 Single-line text field | NOT required
- K2 Single-line text field | NOT required
- K3 Single-line text field | NOT required
- K4 Single-line text field | NOT required

---

**As shown above, there are only two (2) required fields, they are:**

1. B2 - accepts numbers only
2. B3 - accepts numbers only

And the rest are optional, and can leave blank.

**My ultimate goal**: Just fill up the required fields, and submit the form! (Looks pretty straight forward, isn't it?)

But the problem here is, when you submitted the form page. The page will reload and creates a duplicate **Section B** at the bottom of the page and the **Section K** will be removed also. Something like this:

[image]

Surprisingly, when I deleted one (1) section to make it a total of 10 sections OR less than 10 sections then submit the form, the form will be submitted successfully and I would able to see an entry in the reporting database and in form report page.

[image]

---

Anyone encountered this kind of issue before? Is this a known issue? Or a bug?

**Things that I least wanted to try, but just to give a shot:**

1. Clear browser cache, check in most browsers (Firefox, IE and Chrome) - Didn't work
2. IISReset - Didn't work either.

**Supporting files:**

Video: http://screencast.com/t/wtgh2b8M1U

I packaged the form for whoever wanted to try it on their local machine

OneDrive > Download [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ajr_7Ne_eB0ula4KVE1DAS0BXmxfPw). - Do not forget to add section K once installed.

> Appreciate your time and effort. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To answer my question:**

Yes, it is a bug in Sitecore. See the link below on how to implement the Sitecore patch provided by the SC support.

https://sitecorelogy.com/2016/07/19/fixed-sitecore-wffm-creates-a-duplicate-field-section-upon-submission-when-exceeded-to-10-sections/